# how to use ifelse function for all columns in r?

Tags: r

The following code works for 1 column (colname). I want to use this function for all the columns. How to write the below code for all columns?

```
data <- data %>% 
mutate(colname = ifelse(colname == "NA",NA,colname)) %>%
filter(!is.na(colname))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `rowSums` to select rows that have no `"NA"` in them.

```
data <- data[rowSums(data == 'NA', na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
```

In `dplyr` use `if_all` -

```
data <- data %>% filter(if_all(.fns = ~. != 'NA'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R`

```
subset(data, !rowSums(data == 'NA', na.rm = TRUE))
```